# How to place five images attached to each other using ImageViews?

Tags: android, uiimageview, android-imageview

Here is my xml. A gap exists between the images in the graphical layout which I want to avoid. I want all the images being aligned to each other in such a way that the 5 images looks like one single image.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearInteractTab"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:weightSum="5"
    android:layout_margin="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgCall"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/call" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgMsg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/mail" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgComment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/chat" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgDir"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/direction" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgAppt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/calender" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use `framelayout` instead of `linearlayout`. This way images will be overlapped one over the other. :)

Comment: have u tried it and then gave a soln?

Comment: yes ..it did work for me dude :) Just replace linearlayout to framelayout. That did for me. Just images will be overlapped. :)

Comment: ur soln doesnt fits my reqmnt...

Comment: u just wanted the images to be one on top of the other right?

Comment: no, i want the images to place horizontally....

Comment: i mean in that code the images are aligned horizontally only. Better can you show an image as to how you want images to be displayed ?

Answer (score 0):

try removing this line `android:layout_margin="5dp"` from parent linear layout

Comment: then may be your image might be having spaces outside. please check it or try to set layout_width to 0dp of all Imageviews.

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
layout_width="0dp"
```

for all images and remove

```
android:weightSum="5"
```

if all images are of the same size then this is correct:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

if sizes are different it will be hard to align them correctly, but setting fixed size might help.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:weightSum="5" >

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgComment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgComment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgComment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

   </FrameLayout>
```

I just placed 4 images overlapped using the framelayout. I just gave `marginLeft` to show that
images are actually there.